# TAB press for auto-complete does not work for some service names

Tags: command-line, bash, network-manager, services, auto-completion

I can run following command on my Ubuntu 14.04.3 Terminal without any problem:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
[sudo] password for username: 
network-manager stop/waiting
network-manager start/running, process 5204
```

If I type `sudo service network` and then press <kbd>Tab</kbd> it is auto completed to `sudo service networking`.
If I type `sudo service network-ma` and them press <kbd>Tab</kbd> no auto-complete occurs.

My question is if there is a service named `network-manager` that could be restarted by `service` command why its name is not auto-completed? and How to solve it?

**Update:**

```
ls -l /etc/init.d/network*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4479 Apr 28  2014 /etc/init.d/networking
```

Comment: Could you post the output of `ls -l /etc/init.d/network*` just to be sure?

Comment: @terdon The question is updated with the information you asked for.

Answer (score 0):

The tab completion for `service` looks foe files in `/etc/init.d`. Since there is no `network-manager` file there, the tab completion fails. A better question is why `service network-manager` works at all.

According to the `service` man page:

```
   The  SCRIPT  parameter  specifies  a  System  V init script, located in
   /etc/init.d/SCRIPT, or the name of an upstart  job  in  /etc/init.
```

So, since there is a `/etc/init/network-manager.conf` file, `service` can query it, but there is no autocompletion because there is no script of that name in `/etc/init.d`.

A simple workaround would be to create an empty file called `network-manager` in `/etc/init.d`:

```
sudo touch /etc/init.d/network-manager
```

Once you've done that, you can tab-complete the name as expected. I tested this in a VM and it seemed to work fine, the `service network-manager start|stop|restart|status` commands all worked and nothing seemed to be broken. I assume that means that the empty file is ignored and only used for the completion, so it looks like this is safe.